# Proving every element in $1+8\cdot \mathbb{Z}_{2}$ is a square

Tags: number-theory

Let $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ denote the ring of $p$- adic numbers.

- How can I prove that every elements of $1+8\cdot \mathbb{Z}_{2}$ is a square.

I am not comfortable in working $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$'s. So a detailed solution would be of great help and I would learn in future as to how to deal with such problems.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you familiar with Hensel lifting?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I know Hensels's Lemma, but what's Hensel lifting.

Comment: The inductive step in Hensel's Lemma. For example, try to solve the coefficients $a_i\in\{0,1\}$ in the power series
$$
\sqrt{-7}=3+8a_3+16a_4+\cdots
$$
Expand the square of the r.h.s., and see that congruences modulo powers of two will restrict your choices. The difference between $p=2$ and the easier $p>2$ is that here you need a congruence modulo higher power to determine a given coefficient. This is because this time the derivative of $x^2+7$ is divisible by two. Hopefully somebody has time to flesh this out, if you can't work it out on your own. I gotta go.

Comment: I do not understand the question. What are the elements of $1+8Z_2$. Just $\{1,9\}?$

Comment: @PantelisDamianou, read the first line of the question. This is not about the residue class ring of integers, i.e. $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed this is a Hensel's Lemma calculation, in fact a very standard one in the theory of local fields.  It often goes under the name **Local Square Theorem**.  For a statement and proof, see e.g. Lemma 2.11 of [these notes](http://wkchan.web.wesleyan.edu/qflecturenotes.pdf).

Comment: L.Clark: Thanks a lot.